# Steps for creating an optimizer on TensorFlow

Tags: c++, python-2.7, optimization, tensorflow, gradient-descent

I'm trying to implement a new optimizer that consist in a big part of the Gradient Descent method (which means I want to perform a few Gradient Descent steps, then do different operations on the output and then again). Unfortunately, I found 2 pieces of information;

1. You can't perform a given amount of steps with the optimizers. Am I wrong about that? Because it would seem a logical option to add.
2. Given that 1 is true, you need to code the optimizer using C++ as a kernel and thus losing the powerful possibilities of TensorFlow (like computing gradients).

If both of them are true then 2 makes no sense for me, and I'm trying to figure out then what's the correct way to build a new optimizer (the algorithm and everything else are crystal clear).

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

1. I am not 100% sure about that, but I think you are right. But I don't see the benefits of adding such option to TensorFlow. The optimizers based on GD I know usually work like this:

   ```
   for i in num_of_epochs:
       g = gradient_of_loss()
       some_storage = f(previous_storage, func(g))
       params = func2(previous_params, some_storage)
   ```

If you need to perform a couple of optimization steps, you can simply do it in a loop:

```
train_op = optimizer.minimize(loss)
for i in range(10):
    sess.run(train_op)
```

I don't think parameter `multitrain_op = optimizer.minimize(loss, steps)` was needed in the implementation of the current optimizers and the final user can easily simulate it with code before, so that was probably the reason it was not added.

2. Let's take a look at a TF implementation of an example optimizer, Adam: [python code](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/training/adam.py#L128), [c++ code](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/5a566a7701381a5cf7f70fce397759483764e482/tensorflow/core/kernels/training_ops.cc#L224).

The "gradient handling" part is processed entirely by inheriting `optimizer.Optimizer` in python code. The python code only define types of storage to hold the moving window averages, square of gradients, etc, and executes c++ code passing to it the already calculated gradient.

The c++ code has `4` lines, updating the stored averages and parameters.

So to your question "how to build an optimizer":
1 . define what you need to store between the calculations of the gradient
2. inherit `optimizer.Optimizer`
3. implement updating the variables in c++.